# Adding XML tags around current tags in c#

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I'm fairly new to XML and whilst trying to load a series of XML files in through SSIS I've come up against the 'null' value issue when writing the data to a SQL table.

The XML is being provided by a 3rd party supplier and it can't be changed at their end - it is what it is and most of it works fine - it is only one bit of the document that returns this 'null' value problem.

I've read a few articles and found this is down to the XML needing to be wrapped in another root node [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028373/ssis-xmlsource-only-seeing-null-values-in-xml-variable)

So my question is how can I add tags around some current tags? (Shoot me down for the awful wording).

The XML looks something like this:

```
<Parent>

     <info>
       <id>1234</id>
       <secondary_id>ABC-1234</secondary_id>
     </info>

       <Child>Something</child>
       <child2>Something else</child2>
       <child3>Something else here</child3>

     <Summary>
       <text>1234</text>
     </Summary>

</Parent>
```

And what I need to do is dynamically add tags around the child tags above to get something like this:

```
     <info>
       <id>1234</id>
       <secondary_id>ABC-1234</secondary_id>
     </info>

     <info_2>
       <Child>Something</child>
       <child2>Something else</child2>
       <child3>Something else here</child3>
     </info_2>

     <Summary>
       <text>1234</text>
     </Summary>

</Parent>
```

The SSIS uses a foreach to loop through all of the XML files. My theory at this stage is to add a script task, take the current file variable and use it to load and edit the XML and then save it back before the data flow task picks it up and extracts the data.

[image]

I've manually added some tags to one file and it did eliminate the null value problem - so I'm confident it will work.

The current code in my script task is:

```
public void Main()
        {
            //Get the variable from the foreach which contains the current file name.

            string filename = Convert.ToString(Dts.Variables["User::File_Name"]);

            //Create a new XML document object and then load the current file into it.

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(filename);
}
```

But then I have no idea how to add those tags!

Comment: Are you allowed to use LINQ-to-XML i.e [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `XmlDocument`?

Comment: I expect so - how would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find elements which name starts with 'child'
2. Create new parent element `info_2` populated with copy of the found elements as its content
3. Remove original elements found in step 1 from the tree

Here is an example :

```
var raw = @"<Parent>
     <info>
       <id>1234</id>
       <secondary_id>ABC-1234</secondary_id>
     </info>

       <child>Something</child>
       <child2>Something else</child2>
       <child3>Something else here</child3>

     <Summary>
       <text>1234</text>
     </Summary>
</Parent>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);

//step 1
var elements = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("child"));

//step 2
var newElement = new XElement("info_2", elements);
doc.Root.Element("info").AddAfterSelf(newElement);

//step 3:
elements.Remove();

//print result
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Output :

```
<Parent>
  <info>
    <id>1234</id>
    <secondary_id>ABC-1234</secondary_id>
  </info>
  <info_2>
    <child>Something</child>
    <child2>Something else</child2>
    <child3>Something else here</child3>
  </info_2>
  <Summary>
    <text>1234</text>
  </Summary>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Lastly, use `doc.Save(filename)` to write the modified `XDocument` back to disk.

Comment: This certainly looks like where I'm needing to get to! When I add using System.Xml.Linq; to my code it says it can't find the namespace. Probably a dumb question but is there something I have to configure? I'm just using VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution from har07.

I've edited the names, but here is the code which solved my problem:

```
    public void Main()
            {

                string filename = Convert.ToString(Dts.Variables["User::File_Name"].Value);

                XDocument xml = new XDocument();

                var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

                var element1 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("bob"));
                var element2 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("mice"));
                var element3 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("car"));
                var element4 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("dog"));
                var element5 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("cat"));
                var element6 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("number"));
                var element7 = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName.Equals("thing"));

                var newElement = new XElement("New_Tag", element1, element2, element3, element4, element5, element6, element7);
                doc.Root.Element("Some_Tag").AddBeforeSelf(newElement);

                element1.Remove();
                element2.Remove();
                element3.Remove();
                element4.Remove();
                element5.Remove();
                element6.Remove();
                element7.Remove();

                doc.Save(filename);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
```